# How to display UILabel one line at a time in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uilabel

I have a UILabel in a tableView cell that I would like to animate line by line. The string has line breaks with `\n` and `lines.count` returns 7 as expected but no line is being added to the label at all even though the string itself is not nil.

**Code in cellForRow**

```
var index = 0
let lines = messageList[indexPath.row].message.components(separatedBy: "\n")
senderCell.otherUserMessage.numberOfLines = lines.count
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
                    if index != lines.count {
                        let char = lines[index]
                        let nChar = "\n\(char)"
                        senderCell.otherUserMessage.text! += nChar
                        print("char is \(nChar)") //nChar prints the proper text
                        print("senderCellText is \(senderCell.otherUserMessage.text!)") // but this prints an array of numbers
                        // Play sound each time
                         do {
                            self!.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: self!.koalaMessageSound)
                            self!.audioPlayer.play()
                         }catch{
                             // couldn't load file :(
                        }
                        index += 1
                    } else {
                        timer.invalidate()
                    }
                })
```

**Idea/Expected Result**
[image: Idea/Expected Result]

Comment: Does it work without animation?  Do you have `senderCell.otherUserMessagel.numberOfLines = 0;` ?

Comment: Thank you @danh. Yes I have `senderCell.otherUserMessage.numberOfLines = lines.count` I added it to the question now.

Comment: @Dekpe it's not intuitive, but you want numberOfLines set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I found to animate a Label like this was to:
 1. create a copy of Label for each line you have in your original Label (calculating frame.height / lineHeight)
 2. mask each of those copies with rectangles for single line
 3. animate each `Label` separately - each Label will be displaying one line only there so you can control them separately.

Note: Using `\n` is impossible, because sometimes text may go to next line due to it's length on smaller devices, so to get real count of lines, you need to calculate like like I described on point 1.

Comment: Thank you @GrzegorzKrukowski. Do I add the other labels via storyboard? Do you have a code example of carrying this out?

Comment: Hello @GrzegorzKrukowski, have you found the time to write the code?